# adding two arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

The problem is basically printing two arrays on an external array as right part and left part but although I can print one part, I can not print the other part. The scenario is that for example 5 elements on the left and 7 at the right. Then it reverses the right side and sticks it to the beginning of the array.

Here is the piece of code that I typed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
 int mainarray[] = {} , n , i , rank;

 printf("\nHow many element[10..2000]: ");
 scanf("%d", &n);
 printf("\nEnter the array elements : ");
 for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
 {
      scanf("%d" , &mainarray[i]);
 }
 printf("\nThe array is : ");
 for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
 {
     printf("%d ",mainarray[i]);
 }    
 printf("\n\nEnter the rank of the element : ");
 scanf("%d",&rank);
 printf("\n\nElement on rank %d is: %d",rank, mainarray[rank-1]);


 int leftarray[] = {} , rightarray[] = {};

 for(i=0; i<=rank ; i++)
 {
          leftarray[i] = mainarray[i];
 }
 printf("\n\nThe left array is : ");
 for(i=0 ; i<=rank ; i++)
 {
         printf("%d ", leftarray[i]);
 }

 for(i=0 ; i<n-rank-1 ;i++)
 {
              rightarray[i]=mainarray[i+rank+1];
 }
 printf("\n\nThe right array is : ");
 for(i=0 ; i<n-rank-1 ;i++)
 {
         printf("%d ", rightarray[i]);
 }

 int j=n-rank-2,temp;
 i=0;
 while(i<j)
 {
           temp=rightarray[i];
           rightarray[i]=rightarray[j];
           rightarray[j]=temp;
           i++;
           j--;
 }
 printf("\n\nNew right array is : ");
 for(i=0 ; i<n-rank-1 ; i++)
 {
         printf("%d ", rightarray[i]);
 }

 i=0;

 while(i<n-rank-1)
 {
                mainarray[i]=rightarray[i];
                i++;
 }
 j=0;
 while(j<rank+1 && i<n-1)
 {
           mainarray[i]=leftarray[j];
           j++;
           i++;
 }

 printf("\n\nThe result is : ");
 for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
 {
         printf("%d ",mainarray[i]);
 }    

 printf("\n\n\n");
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int mainarray[] = {}` - ouch. if you were shooting for an array that can hold no elements, you found it.

Comment: When you do `int mainarray[] = {}` you define `mainarray`as an *empty* array. All indexing of it will be out of bounds.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &n); int mainarray[n];`

Comment: How can I create an array without declaring the size?  @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring empty arrays when you write:

```
int mainarray[] = {};
```

As a result, you're storing outside the array bounds, which results in undefined behavior.

You need to declare the arrays *after* you get the size from the user.

```
scanf("%d", &n);
int mainarray[n]; // no need to initialize here, you're going to fill it in with the input loop
```

Then do similar things for `leftarray` and `rightarray`:

```
scanf("%d",&rank);
int leftarray[rank];
int rightarray[n-rank];
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Barmar the problem will be solved after some tiny changes.